# In Apache Atlas, is there a way to delete/clean soft deleted entities after enabling hard delete?

Tags: apache-atlas

We used to have soft delete and recently enabled hard delete in atlas 1.1. Now we are trying to clean up the soft deleted entities via delete by guid api and not able to clear those. Is there a way to delete/clean soft deleted entities after enabling hard delete?

Even I tried updating the entities with active status to make it active, but the status is still "DELETED".

Apache Atlas Version: 1.1

API: DELETE /v2/entity/guid/{guid}

Answer (score 1):

Atlas seems to have added purge API(`/admin/purge`) to delete soft deleted Entities.

You can go through the jira: `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ATLAS-3477` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
----------------soft

curl -iv -u admin:admin -X DELETE http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/88f13750-f2f9-4e31-89f7-06d313fe5d39



---------------- than hard



curl -i -X PUT  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-u admin:admin 'http://loclahost:21000/api/atlas/admin/purge/' \
-d '["88f13750-f2f9-4e31-89f7-06d313fe5d39"]'
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to include some additional explanation? That would make this a more user answer than just including the commands.